# How to disable updates for a host in Munin but keep the historical graphs?

Tags: munin

I need to disable updates for a particular host but I want to keep the graphs for historical data.

I've tried using `update no` on the host definition in munin.conf but that removes the host from the overview etc.  This isn't quite what I was expecting based on the docs.

The HTML and images are (obviously) still there in /var/www/html/munin and I can still load the URL manually, but I'd like it to be listed in the overview.

Answer (score 1):

Change the plugin to output "nan" (not a number) every time it is called. This will cause munin to not plot anything.

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the `munin-node` running on the device you no longer wish to monitor. Unfortunately stats will still try to update and graphs will flatline but historical data will be preserved.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do this since the graphs in question are all running on the local munin-node. They are plugins which check remote HTTP services. I guess I could modify the plugins to always return '0' or something.